# Not able to pass the test in SonarQube :: Code Smell : getting Line to long in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, sonarqube, application.properties

When Springboot application is deployed and being checked in Jenkins pipeline with help of sonarQube

Issues are reported as codesmells in application.properties that a property is too long

```
jdbc:as400://<hostname>;date format=iso;naming=system;transaction isolation=none;
```

> line too long (105 > 80 characters) (line-length)

Tried with giving the backlash(\) in property value but it is not working

Comment: You don't have to do what SonarQube says. This is a reasonable oneliner property. In SonarQube, you can mark it as "Won't fix".

Comment: properties file is in yml

Answer (score 0):

If your project has `sonar.properties` file , you can also mention explicit exclusion

```
sonar.exclusions=src/java/resources/application.properties
```

or

```
sonar.exclusions=src/java/resources/**
```

Comment: are there any steps for adding sonar.properties

Comment: If project is using Sonar dependency, it should automatically come, however, I am unsure, you can try creating and check if it works!